# Connection Failure warning when generating schema for a local sqlite database using SchemaSpy

Tags: sqlite, connection, schemaspy

I tried the following steps to generate schema for a local sqlite database using SchemaSpy, but a Warning "Connection Failure" occurs and no schema is generated.

- Downloaded sqlite dll from [here](https://sqlite.org/2019/sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3270200.zip), unziped and added to Windows System32 Folder.
- Downloaded sqlite jbdc driver from [here](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads/sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1.jar), and added to the same folder where local database MyDataBase.db and schemaspy-6.0.0.jar are located.
- Tried out the following command line in order to generate the schema:

cd C:\Data\Projects\MyProject\DataBase

java -jar schemaspy-6.0.0.jar -t sqlite -db MyDataBase.db -dp sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1.jar -o C:\Data\Projects\MyProject\DataBase -u Mateus Ferreira

Once the database is local, it doesn´t have any user associated, Once it is a requried flag, I tried adding the same one as the windows user.

The execution is returning the following log:

> "SchemaSpy generates an HTML representation of a database schema's
>   relationships.
>
> SchemaSpy comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
>
> SchemaSpy is free software and can be redistributed under the
>   conditions of LGPL version 3 or later. http://www.gnu.org/licenses/
>
> INFO  - Starting Main v6.0.0 on MateusPC with PID 4976
>   (C:\Data\Projects\MyProject\DataBase\schemaspy-6.0.0.jar started by
>   Mateus Ferreira in C:\Data\Projects\MyProject\DataBase)
>
> INFO  - The following profiles are active: default
>
> INFO  - Started Main in 19.369 seconds (JVM running for 28.19)
>
> INFO  - Configuration file not found
>
> INFO  - Starting schema analysis
>
> **WARN  - Connection Failure**"

**Is there someone who knows what I could be doing wrong?**

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error and managed to overcome after reading https://github.com/schemaspy/schemaspy/issues/524. I created a sqlite.properties file as follows:

```
description=SQLite
driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
driverPath=sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.jar
connectionSpec=jdbc:sqlite:<db>
db=mydatabase.db
```

and issued the following command:

```
java -jar schemaspy-6.0.0.jar -t sqlite -o ./output/ -db mydatabase.db -cat mydatabase -s mydatabase -sso
```